# Using HTTP get with Google geocode APO

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map inside an html file and am using HTTP get with jquery to grab a devices location.  I need this then to be passed onto the map but can not get the map to plot these.  I need to parse the given location and then plot it on the map. This is my code so far but it gives the data as an alert.

```
function initialize() {



var mapOptions = {
zoom: 6,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(41, -87)//I need my data here
 }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);

var image = 'images/marker';
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875680, -87.61883);//i need my data here
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: image
 });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


setInterval(initialize,10000);




$.get("this is where i have the url for the get ", function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  var pairs = data.split('&');
  alert(pairs[1])


  for (i in pairs){
  var split = pairs[i].split('=');
    if (split[0] == "lat") {
        lat = split[1];
    }

    else if (split[0] == "lng") {
        lng = split[1];
    }
}
coordinate = lat.concat(",");
coordinate = coordinate.concat(lng);
alert(coordinate);

});
```

I need the data loaded to not show up in an alert but to be replaced by the lat and long points that are in the map code.  How do I put my coordinate data into the map code?

Answer (score 0):

You should store your map, and perhaps your markers as a global variable, so that you can refer to it later when your query come back with the result.

then you can use

```
    map.setCenter(myLatLng);
    marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
```

to update both the center of your map, and the position of your marker.

I created a quick demo here, hope this help
http://jsfiddle.net/asw32w5m/